# for loop delay in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to set delay in for loop execution

```
for(i=0; i<=10;i++){
        var s=i;//This line should execute for every 2 secs only
        }
```

How to give loop delay in java script....

**I dont want like below..I want without using setTimeout...**

```
for(i=0; i<=10;i++){
        setTimeout("setvalue()",2000); //This alert should display for every 2 secs only
        }

        function setvalue()
        {
         var s=i;
        }
```

please help me...

Comment: So you want a delay without using the exact feature built into javascript to do a delay?

Comment: Why **don't** you want to use `setTimeout`?

Comment: If you call something like a sleep, the browser will freeze for the whole loop duration. Are you sure you used the callback correctly ? Because the code you placed won't work.

Comment: -1, because you're asking for a problem to be solved and for some obscure reason, demanding that the very part of the API that exists to solve your problem, to not be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Answer (score 9):

Use `setInterval()`

```
var i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    setValue();
    i += 1;

    if(i == 10)
        clearInterval(interval);
}, 2000);
```

There is no way to *sleep* for 2sec without freezing the whole browser. Javascript is single threaded.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. JS runs in a single thread and any attempt to delay that thread will freeze the entire page. Using setTimeout is your only option.

EDIT: or setInterval; either way, there is no non-hairy way to express "halt execution here for x milliseconds."

Answer (score 2):

Using `setTimeout` is inevitable, however, a recursive function might be a better solution for this one:

```
var i=0;
function recurs() {
    i = s;
    i++;
    if (i <= 10) recurs();
}

recurs();
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, `setTimeout` can be used very well to handle these sorts of scenarios and `setInterval` could also be used but is discouraged by some.

You can even recursively call a function that has setTimeout built into it as mentioned in the MDN documentation of [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval#Dangerous_usage). The heading there mentions 'dangerous usage' but their solution to the danger is the block of code beneath.

There it mentions that to have a loop executing every x seconds (or milliseconds) then you can do the following and know for sure that the functions will only be executing one at a time **and in-sequence**:

```
(function loop(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // logic here

        // recurse
        loop();

    }, 1000); // repeat loop 1 second after this branch has completed
})();
```

And if you want it to only do that a limited number of times, then you can create a variable outside of the loop and only recursively execute if the count is smaller than the number of times you want to execute for. Such as this:

```
var count = 0;
(function loop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // logic
        count++;
        if (count < 10) {
            loop();
        }
    }, 1000);
})();
```